# Stackdriver Workspace availability

Tags: stackdriver

I have a GAE application in US Central (say Project A)  and another GAE application in US East1 (say Project B). I want one Stackdriver dashboard to monitor these two together. Hence I merged Project B onto Project A's workspace which is in Central. Now I have a merged dashboard.

Question - Assume a scenario when US central region went down and my project A workspace is not available. Will this make my merged dashboard completely unavailable (including east region monitoring too)?

Answer (score 1):

Stackdriver Monitoring is a global service and is designed to survive outages in a given region or zone. While an outage in a given region or zone could impact ingesting time-series data in that region/zone, your workspace configuration (including dashboards, alerting policies, etc.) should be available even with such an outage. Alerting policies that do not perform a cross-series aggregation across different locations should continue working and firing alerts when there is a regional outage (policies that aggregate time-series across locations may, however, malfunction in such situations). It should be noted that the underlying time-series database and alert delivery infrastructure that underlies Stackdriver Monitoring is also used for Google's own internal monitoring and is relied on by Google SRE teams to be notified of outages in Google's own systems, including outages caused by zones or regions being taken offline by fiber cuts, disasters, and other issues.